# Is it possible to define meta data of a placeholder in php word template?

Tags: phpword

I am implementing a feature in my web application where I create documents from templates. I am using PHP word template processor for it. I have the following questions:

- How can I define styling of each placeholder separately?
- I need to fetch data from different database tables depending on the template and placeholder. Is there a way that I can define metadata for it inside the template?